# C# - Creating a configuration file to save data used in the application

Tags: c#, mysql, xml, configuration-files

my project has been an extremely fun journey so far but I am looking to save the configuration of the Server settings that it will connect (using MySQL Net/Connector).

When the application has loaded up, by default it connects to a server named 'sqlserver05' but I want the user/admin to be able to configure the server settings in a menustrip. So I navigate to the menustrip and you can click 'Configure' where another form pops up asking for server details.

I can do this just by a global string but I have to change the settings everytime the application runs. Can I not create an XML file to read the configuration settings that I just changed?

Sorry if I am not being clear. Many thanks,

Brandon

Comment: Yes, you can. (Allthough this answers your question, I dont think you are looking for this answer, so, please update your question to specify what you want to know, and show us what you've tried to reach that goal).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. An easy way to do this is to use application settings. This is an out-of-the-box implementation of (user and program) settings that is serialized to XML.

Please take a look at the ancient, but still applicable [Using Settings in C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869(v=vs.80).aspx).

Effectively what you have to do:

- Add a settings file to your project. Go the the *Solution Explorer*, right click on your project and select *Properties*. Then select *Settings*. Follow the steps there.
- Create a setting. (In the following code it has the name `PropertyName`)
- Get and set that setting in code.

  ```
  string value = Properties.Settings.PropertyName; // get
  Properties.Settings.Default.PropertyName = value; // set
  ```
- Save the settings when you have changed anything:

  ```
  Properties.Settings.Default.Save()
  ```

Comment: Many thanks, this is exactly what I needed and got it working in that amount of short time.

Answer (score 0):

I think in your case it's better to use the Settings class that came with C#, take a look at these links.
[1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869(v=vs.80).aspx) , [2](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17659/How-To-Use-the-Settings-Class-in-C)

Comment: Thank you for the links. :)

Comment: @BrandonSpendlove not a bad idea to vote up when you get your answer or help :) ;)

Comment: I voted everyone up although it doesn't publicly show until I earn a total of 15 reputation. :(

Answer (score 0):

First of all, create a simple POCO object to handle the value you wish to set, then read / write this object through a serializer.

You could use a Javascript serializer to generate a JSON file (which is more "trendy" than XML, but if you prefer XML, the mechanism remains the same) :

```
class DatabaseSettings
{
    // Settings file path
    private const string DEFAULT_FILENAME = "settings.json";
    // Server name or IP
    public string Server { get; set; } = "127.0.0.1";
    // Port
    public int Port { get; set; } = 3306;
    // Login
    public string Login { get; set; } = "root";
    // Password
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public void Save(string fileName = DEFAULT_FILENAME)
    {
        File.WriteAllText(
            fileName,
            (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Serialize(this));
    }

    public static DatabaseSettings Load(string fileName = DEFAULT_FILENAME)
    {
        var settings = new DatabaseSettings();
        if (File.Exists(fileName))
            settings = (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Deserialize<DatabaseSettings>(File.ReadAllText(fileName));
        return settings;
    }
}
```

Usage is then the following :

```
// Read
var settings = DatabaseSettings.Load(/* your path */);
// update
settings.Server = "10.10.10.2";
// save
settings.Save(/* your path */);
```

Comment: I may try this method in the future, but the other method from the settings in the solution explorer fit my current needs. Many thanks for the detailed answer.

Comment: We all posted basically together, and I also prefer the methods using the built-in settings... Not sure if it is still working with .Net Framework 5.